# Scheme storing the result of a function (Let)

Tags: list, scheme

```
(define [DML vara] 
  (cond
     ((atom? (car vara)) 
      (cond
        ((eqan? (car vara) 'N)
         (display (cdr vara)))
        (else (negate vara)))

   )))
```

I'm currently trying to save the content of a return right now for simplicity I was testing the negate function it "returns" a list and I wanted to save the result of that function to do testing. How do I actually save the list return from negate. 
Kind of like (x = (negate vara)) where x is the list. I look up let on google and in stack over flow but I can't find a very simple basic assignment.

Excuse my poor syntax on scheme I'm just starting..and going from imperative language to function isn't so smooth..

edit:

I wanted to print out the result expression of (negate vara) but since scheme only prints out the last "recursive call" (pardon my bad wording). I wanted it to use the resulting list from (negate vara) but still print out that list like

```
say if I had 
(else (test (negate vara)))
...
(define (test vara)
(display "test")
)

I wanted it to display 
'(O a b)) ;list
here
```

Comment: The pseudocode isn't clear. Why don't you write a complete, _working_ example (meaning: one that compiles and actually runs) of what you want, in another programming language of your choice?

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, a `let` expression will do the trick:

```
(let ((x 10)
      (y 20))
  (+ x y))

=> 30
```

The above expression binds values to two variables, `x` and `y`. These bindings will exist inside the body of the `let`. Implicitly, all the expressions in the `let` form are packed inside a `begin`, and the end result of the whole expression is the final expression. Notice that one binding cannot refer to the others in the definition part; if one variable needs to refer to previous definitions, then use a `let*`:

```
(let* ((x 10)
       (y (* x 2)))
  (+ x y))

=> 30
```

Finally, if you need to create a recursive definition use `letrec`:

```
(letrec ((fact (lambda (x)
                 (if (zero? x) 1 (* x (fact (sub1 x)))))))
  (fact 10))

=> 3628800
```

Comment: Hmm so how do I save the 30 to a new list that I can call later with like (dispaly z) to show the updated content?

Comment: Why don't you show the result right there? remember: the variables inside a `let` only exist in the scope of its body, it's the same as any other programming language that defines scopes. It'd be useful if you showed as part of the question what _exactly_ do you want to do, use pseudocode or code in another programming language to demonstrate your point.

Comment: Also notice that if you want to save the result to some list "outside" the `let`, you're going to need mutable state, and although it's possible, it wouldn't be a functional programming-style approach in the spirit of Scheme. Maybe you should reevaluate your approach, and adjust it to a functional style.

Comment: I updated the question with kind of what I had in mind to do. I know that this isn't the way the language was design to work. Is there another way around to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a procedure like you proposed:

```
(define (test var)
  (display var)
  var)
(test (negate (test vara)))) ; prints our argument and return
```

Or you could use DrRacket and use the debugger. You'll miss it after using it once!